# Java define date format using mapstruct

Tags: mapstruct

I'm using mapstruct for mapping my entities.
All my entities have a date field.
Is there a way to define a date formatter on the level of the mapper, instead of adding a mapping for each field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is not possible. However, one can achieve what you are looking for by implementing a custom mapping methods within your mappers. In there you can use your own pattern.